# Using ANT with multiple XSD and single XJB

Tags: ant, binding, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have a custom external XJB file that has the schema name within it as follows :

**jxb:bindings schemaLocation="completeCheck.xsd" node="/xs:schema"**

Just wondering, is there a way to substitute the schema name at runtime within the XJB file using ANT(using ANT XJC) OR have a xjb binding file written such that I do not have to hardcode the schema name in it. Basically, I am trying to see if I can use a single xjb file for multiple XSDs.

Currently, I have the same xjb file all over the place with a different hardcoded schema name referred all over the place in build.xml. Any pointers are highly appreciated. I am using JAXB 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Make a template from your xjb file by replacing the value of your schemaLocation attribute with some sort of marker (e.g. !!!) and save it using some other name/extension. Define a macro with an attribute such as schema-name that will use ant's replace to change the marker in the template file with your schema name and save that as the binding file to be subsequently used by xjc.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in the latest versions of XJC, you can use schema component designator. More info here :
https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#scd and https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_SCD_for_customizations.html